# suggest me the different options to store this data in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am getting the data in the following format

[Sl.No, Amount, Transaction Type, Account Number]

---

[01, $10000, Deposit, 473882829]

---

[02, $10202, Deposit, 348844844]

---

[02, $10202, Withdrawal, 348844844]

What is the best way to store this data in Javascript for faster retrieval

Comment: if you add labels to it, you can easily keep it as a JS object

Comment: @JohnP - or [JSON](http://www.json.org/)

Comment: @timbooo JSON is just text -- used for transmission or storage -- while a "JS object" can be constructed from JSON (or manually from one-off formats, such as above).

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = ["02", "$10202", "Withdrawal", 348844844]

//empty object
var list = {};

//Constructing the index by concatenating the last two elements of the data.
//Probably this will give the primary key to the data.
var index = data[2] + data[3].toString();

//Store the data using the index
list[index] = data;
```

You can retrieve the data using the index constructed above.

Comment: This is invalid as it parses to the identifier `$` followed by the number `10202` -- perhaps `['02', '$102002', "Withdrawal", ...]`. Also, `0xyz` (where x y and z 0 to 7) is treated as octal, hence the quote on the first element as well (also preserves leading 0's). Same should likely go for last.

Comment: @pst:I agree. yes the data should be converted to string. modifying the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Determine how the data needs to be accessed. I am guessing it needs to be accessed linearly, so as to not accidentally overdraw (withdraw before deposit), etc -- in this case an Array is generally a suitable data structure. A simple for-loop should be able to find most simple "queries".
2. Define how the object is represented in Javascript -- is each "transaction item" an array of `[x, amount, type, account]` or is it an object with the signature `{x: ..., amount: ..., type: ..., account: ...}` (I often opt for the latter as it adds some self-documentation). It could also be an object created with `new TransactionItem` (or whatnot) that includes methods.
3. Determine how to convert the raw data into the chosen object representation. For a well-defined format a simple regular expression or 'split' may work.
4. Use data. Remember that even a shoddy `O(n^2)` algorithm is generally "fast enough" for small `n`. Best to get it working first.

Happy coding.